# Can positive lookahead regex be used for redirects?

Tags: regex, redirect

Current urls:

- /product/1123281&cbx301425/
- /product/2565285&cbx301425&cbx674390/
- /product/2565285&cbx278426&cbx325387&cbx789649/

Desired urls:

- /product/1123281/cbx301425/
- /product/2565285/cbx301425/cbx674390/
- /product/2565285/cbx278426/cbx325387/cbx789649/

I would like to change every instance of "&cbx" to "/cbx" with a redirect.

What I have tried:
RewriteRule &(?=cbx) / [L,R=301]

Can a positive lookahead regexs for redirect?

Comment: Can you not just replace `&cbx` with `/cbx`? Why do you need a lookahead?